# Attach an "after insert" trigger on the tables "tracks" that recalculates the "play_time" value to ensure that it is always correct. Not working?

Tags: r, sqlite, rsqlite

I have a HW assignment using the " Media.db" commonly used for SQL exercises.

First we added a new column to the " albums" table called "play time".

Then I added a constraint to make sure the values added to the table are only positive values.

Then I made an update statement that updates the new "play_time' column to contain the total play time for an album based on the tracks it contains.

But I'm having trouble with this last part:

Attach an "after insert" trigger on the tables "tracks" that recalculates the "play_time" value to ensure that it is always correct. So, for example, if a new track is added to an album, then the "play_time" column is updated.

Using RSQLite in R, this is what I have:
Here is what I Have:

```
# add the trigger
step_4 <- paste0(" CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS
                  AFTER INSERT  TrackId ON tracks
                 FOR EACH ROW
                 WHEN
                 BEGIN
                    (UPDATE albums 
                  SET play_time = ( SELECT 
                      COUNT(play_time)
                  FROM
                      tracks
                  INNER JOIN albums ON albums.albumid = tracks.albumid
                  GROUP BY 
                      tracks.albumid))
                 "
  
)
rs4 <- dbExecute(dbcon,step_4)
```

This is what I keep getting:

Error: near "TrackId": syntax error

Please help.

I tried changing the syntax, using Inner_join differently,

and this is what I did make an update statement that updates the new "play_time' column to contain the total play time for an album based on the tracks it contains.

```
# update the "play_time" column 
step_3 <- paste0(" UPDATE albums 
                  SET play_time = ( SELECT 
                    tracks.albumid
                    title
                    COUNT(play_time)
                  FROM
                      tracks
                  INNER JOIN albums ON albums.albumid = tracks.albumid
                  GROUP BY 
                      tracks.albumid)
                  WHERE
                      play_time
                  
")

rs3 <- dbExecute(dbcon,step_3)
```

Comment: Why not just use a [view](https://sqlite.org/lang_createview.html)?

Comment: `using the " Media.db" commonly used for SQL exercises` ... perhaps not common to all. What is `Media.db`?

Comment: @Shawn, I suspect this is an exercise on database design and management, not on how to get the correct data. I could be wrong ...

Comment: Right, this is for homework! It's on database design coursework.

Comment: The db is freely available on this website:  https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/